# How can I use 'contains()' method in better way in my code

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist

```
$source = @("1234-abc","1234-xyz","34-pqr","3456-xyz","456-pp")
$name = @()

foreach($sr in $source)
{
    $array = $sr -split "-"
    $ID = $array[0]

    if ($sr.contains($ID))
    {
        $name += Sr.split("-",1) +","
    }
}
```

expected output:

`1234` contains `1234-abc`, `1234-xyz`

`34` contains `34-pqr`

`3456` contains `3456-xyz`

`456` contains `456-pp`

but, as I have used `contains()` 34's value is coming along with 1234 and same thing is happening with 456 and 3456.

please help me out

Comment: This is no a solution as such but I advise you to start looking at regular expressions and -match operator.

Comment: Hi, I have tried -match as well, but it also combines 34 values with 1234

Comment: Can you explain a bit better whats the goal of your function? The Code doesn't work as it throws an exception.

Comment: I found the issue, -like is working for this condition

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Group-Object` to group the strings by their prefix:

`"1234-abc","1234-xyz","34-pqr","3456-xyz","456-pp" | Group-Object {$_.Split('-')[0]}`

Which gives output like this:

```
Count Name Group               
----- ---- -----               
    2 1234 {1234-abc, 1234-xyz}
    1 34   {34-pqr}            
    1 3456 {3456-xyz}          
    1 456  {456-pp}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Use | to send values to next command
@('1234-abc', '1234-xyz', '34-pqr', '3456-xyz', '456-pp', '34-abcd', 'xxxx33333') |
    ForEach-Object {
        # ForEach-Object will loop through each value
        # $_ represents the current object 
        # use -match operator to check if object ($_) matches pattern.  Regex is used 
        if ($_ -match '^(?<Id>\d+?)-(?<Value>.*)') {
            # If match was successful an automatic variable called $Matches is populated

            # [PSCustomObject] and hashtable @{key = value } create a new object.
            # Here we create an object that contains the Id and the value previously
            # found by -match.  
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Id = $Matches.Id
                Value = $Matches.Value
            }

            # Not assigning the object  to a variable automatically sends it out down
            #  the pipeline to the next command

            # Could have also created the object using Select-Object and calculated properties
            # shown below: 
            # # $Matches | Select-Object @{n = 'Id'; e = {$_.Id}}, @{n = 'Value'; e = {$_.Value}}
        }
        else {
            # If value doesn't match the regex create an object that passes this 
            # down the pipeline as well
            [pscustomobject]@{Id = 'No Match'; Value = $_ }
        }
    } |
    # Group objects by Id using Group-Object 
    Group-Object -Property Id |
    # Another ForEach-Object to process each of our new groupings
    # containing our pscustomobjects with Id and Value. Since each group is 
    # being sent 1 at a time we can use this to display each group and the values.
    # Groups will contain a Name property generated based off the property being grouped: Id 
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "** $($_.Name) **" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $_.Group.Value
    }
```

Output will look like this

```
** 1234 **
abc
xyz

** 34 **
pqr
abcd

** 3456 **
xyz

** 456 **
pp

** No Match **
xxxx33333
```

Here is the same code as above without all the comments

```
@('1234-abc', '1234-xyz', '34-pqr', '3456-xyz', '456-pp', '34-abcd', 'xxxx33333') |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^(?<Id>\d+?)-(?<Value>.*)') {
            [PSCustomObject]@{Id = $Matches.Id; Value = $Matches.Value}
        }
        else {
            [pscustomobject]@{Id = 'No Match'; Value = $_ }
        }
    } |
    Group-Object -Property Id |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "** $($_.Name) **" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $_.Group.Value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]]::new([System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
@("1234-abc","1234-xyz","34-pqr","3456-xyz","456-pp") |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $indexOfDelimeter = $_.indexOf('-')
        $key = $_.Substring(0, $indexOfDelimeter).ToUpperInvariant()
        if (-not $result.ContainsKey($key)) {
            $result[$key] = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
        }
        $result[$key].Add($_)
    }
```

Result:

```
# $result 

Key  Value               
---  -----               
1234 {1234-abc, 1234-xyz}
34   {34-pqr}            
3456 {3456-xyz}          
456  {456-pp}
```